# Select rows from table except the ones present in another table - DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a logic in my DB2 Stored Procedure as follows. Please explain what the statement inside while do and when it enters the loop.

Logic:

```
while (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_1 EXCEPT SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2)
DO
   -- Statements
END WHILE;
```

Please note TABLE_1 AND TABLE_2 are identical to each other with same columns, but data may vary. On frequent basis, data on TABLE_1 is inserted to TABLE_2 and TABLE_1 is refreshed.

Comment: If your intention is to run the loop body when rows exist in Table_1 that are not present in Table_2, then your code should use `select *` instead of `select 1` for both tables.

Comment: Is there a way just to check data on table_1 but not on table_2 in the while loop using 1 or something rather than * that fetches bunch of data? Tables may have huge data going forward.

Comment: Data on Table_1 refreshes/cleared frequently but not Table_2. So row count of T2 is always greater :( Looking for a tweak with that select 1 logic

Comment: Don't know your logic, but after copying rows into the target, do you delete from source table?

Comment: Yes, load the data to T1, process the data, copy to T2. This happens everyday. At weekend, clear data on T1. T2 acts as archive table. So need a logic to copy the rows to T2 that are only on source but not on T2. Anyhow, copy is like - INSERT TO T2 (SELECT * FROM T1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM T2)

Comment: Don't you have a proper **PK** or **Unique index** on both tables ? If not, you should! this will become extremely slow without a proper PK/Unique index after T2 becomes larger and larger. Then,  this becomes really trivial,  and you don't even need a SP. `INSERT INTO TABLE_2 SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT T2.PK FROM TABLE_2 T2 WHERE T1.PK = T2.PK )` and similar queries